# No resource found that matches the given name?

Tags: android

I have a trip planer application which is done using Android studio.
I get the following error while trying to run it.

```
No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
```

Comment: can you post your `build.gradle` for this module?

Comment: @VeneetReddy i added the build.gradle, could you help ?

Comment: Try updating your support lib versions to 22.2.1

Comment: Did this help ?

Answer (score 0):

```
make a color.xml:

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
        <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
        <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
        <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>

        <color name="colorBackground">#0097E3</color>
        <color name="light_blue">#3F51B5</color>
        <color name="grey">#303F9F</color>
    </resources>

Change Theme in Style:-




    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">#4E86FF</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#3e6bcc</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    </style>
and tempopary Comment on 

<!--<meta-data-->
            <!--android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"-->
            <!--android:value="@string/google_maps_api_key" />-->

Change Gradle With this One:



            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, have you test that ?

Comment: after changing in gradle ,style & Classpath   ,this work fine

Comment: my project before the edition is in my post. Could upload the full project after your edition ?

Comment: in your project i have to change only few things that mentioned in above.

Comment: When i tried your suggestions i getmore error, could you please upload the project to google drive or somewhere ?